# Upgrade from Eazfuscator free... to confuserex?

Tags: obfuscation, eazfuscator

I'm using VS 2008 and Eazfuscator latest free version and I want to upgrade to VS 2013. Eazfuscator latest free version doesn't work with VS 2013 and I took also a free obfuscator:Confuserex,is that a good one?
I found there is a Deobfuscator for that,so it is not safe? 
https://github.com/UbbeLoL/ConfuserDeobfuscator

If not,a good free choice?

It is a way to integrate it with VS and automatic obfucation on build,Eazfuscator works that way.
thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working with these settings:
Preset: aggressive
Protection: remove antidebug

Answer (score 2):

I chosen confuserex and I found a way to integrate it with VS

http://dev.schausberger.cc/2013/05/obfuscating-visual-studio-net-2010-code-before-creating-setup-project/

This the code found,needs to be added to .vbproj file

```
if $(ConfigurationName)==Release (

    cd “$(TargetDir)”
    “c:\path_to_\confuser Release\confuser.console.exe”   “$(SolutionDir)confuserSettings.crproj”
    copy /y Confused\*.*
    rmdir /s /q Confused
    ) else (
    echo “not in release mode, not obfuscating”
    )
```

and I use:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PostBuildEvent>
    If $(ConfigurationName)==Release (
        cd $(TargetDir)
        c:\Confuser\Confuser.CLI.exe $(ProjectDir)confuserSettings.crproj
    )
   </PostBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

confuserSettings.crproj is confuser project

the only thing I could not resolved is to use in build mode obfuscated file

i think these commands is doing that:

```
       copy /y Confused\*.*
       rmdir /s /q Confused
```

I don't used them because I got this error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJaWH.png

how can I fix it,thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Eazfuscator works with any Visual Studio version. Support for the latest versions of the frameworks (.Net 4.5, WinRT, .Net 5) is however missing.